# asp-action helper not working for index action

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I think I'm going crazy perhaps. I've got a controller (TrainingOfficer) which has some methods, but in particular it has Index():

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{  
//does stuff, returns a view
}
```

I then wanted to link to that controller/action, so I wrote out:

```
<a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="TrainingOfficer" asp-action="Index">Training</a>
```

But unfortunately razor drops the "Index" method and simply returns (not there is no /Index):

```
<a class="nav-link" href="/TrainingOfficer">Training</a>
```

Which is all well and good, except that when I leave "/Index" off the url it now just prints "value" to the screen:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/4m0OdSC.jpg]

Continuing on with the weirdness:

1. If I travel to TrainingOfficer/Index, it works fine and as expected.
2. If I rename Index to IndexLOL, and put IndexLOL as the asp-action in the link, the href tag looks great and everything works.

**Why is this having such a problem with a method named Index?**

Even odder, I'm pretty sure this worked just fine with no changes for a month and then recently started showing this behavior. I upgraded my .Net Core nuget package so perhaps that's the culprit.

Comment: You are using the default route which has `Index` as the default action, therefore the `/Index` is omitted (which is the default behavior). And if you had `asp-controller="Home"` you would see the url as just `/` because `Home` is the default controller.

Comment: @StephenMuecke any ideas on why, when "/index" is omitted it just says "value" ?

Comment: Seems odd. What is the code in your `Index()` method?